# how to retain viewModel properties between actions

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with two dropdowns.

```
if (Model.Categories != null)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "UniqueId", "Name", Model.SelectedCategory), new { onchange = @"form.action='/Home/Index';form.submit();" })
}

if (Model.Projects != null)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProject, new SelectList(Model.Projects, "UniqueId", "Name", Model.SelectedProject), new { @onchange = @"form.action='/Home/UpdateTasks';form.submit();" })
}

@Html.ActionLink("View Project", "Project", new { id = Model.SelectedProject })
```

The controller action  to perform when second dropdownlist item is selected would be  as below.

```
public ActionResult UpdateTasks(ProjectViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        viewModel.Projects = this._projectService.Projects(viewModel.SelectedCategory);

        viewModel.Tasks = this._projectService.Tasks(viewModel.SelectedProject);                
    }
        return View("Index", viewModel);    
    }
```

The problem is, once the user clicks on the 'View Project' link, it will take to the new action method with id as  input parameter and returns
a view. On  that  view there is a return to previous page option which should point to UpdateTasks method, it is however  going back to that method
but viewModel properties are null.

How do I retain viewModel properties between actions?

I was thinking to change the UpdateTasks method to be like below as I need only the SelectedCategory and SelectedProject

```
public ActionResult UpdateTasks(int projectid, int categoryid)
{
......
}
```

But how do I pass both selected  project and category parameters to on change event in the dropdownlistfor?

I tried to change the onchange event as below to pass multiple parameters but there seems to be problem in the structure since categoryId is null.

```
var abc = Model.SelectedCategory;
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProject, new SelectList(Model.Projects, "UniqueId", "Name", Model.SelectedProject), new { @onchange = "document.location.href = '/Home/UpdateTasks/?projectId=' + this.value + '&categoryId=' + abc;" })
```

Comment: You don't retain them. You repopulate them. Whatever methodology you used initially, you should also use on other actions that need that information.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I have changed the action method with two input parameters rather than viewmodel by passing in parameters to jquery onchange event. There is no option to reply to this post with complete code.  But got solved by writing window.location.href = '@Url.Action("UpdateTasks","Home")' + '?projectId=' + projectId + '&categoryId=' + categoryId; in onchange event